# how to offset form in vb

Tags: vb.net, winforms, offset, gmap.net

the question is rather simple, but what I am working on is not..
this is a marker from a control called [GMaps.NET](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/)
[image]

the next picture is a form, that follows the marker when I drag the map, something like the InfoWindow on google maps API.
only problem is that, it covers the marker, and I can't offset it no matter how hard I think.[image]

this is my current code..

```
Private Sub map_OnMapDrag() Handles map.OnMapDrag        
    Form2.Show()
    Form2.Location = camera1.LocalPosition 
End Sub
```

please list some ways on how I can offset it so we can see the marker.. thanks!

**Reminder :** you can't directly use `camera1.LocalPosition`'s `Point` because its coordinates are inside the map. whilst `Form2.Location` is on the form. though the same value, they are worlds apart :)
so give different options that I can try TIA

Comment: Can you not just create a new point that is `camera1.LocalPosition` plus some arbitrary amount? I thought point was a struct anyway so adding another `Point` to it will result in another instance (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point(v=vs.110).aspx) so can you not use `camera1.LocalPosition + new Point(10,10)` or something similar?

Comment: I don't get you, but if I create another `Point` the form's location will be on that point and then it cannot be dragged along with the marker.

Comment: good thing I asked. I am pretty sure that I used that equation a while ago.. wonder why it gave an error. thanks! @Charleh

Comment: `OnMapDrag` is called multiple times as you drag the map. Point is a struct and when assigning it you are making a copy of the values - it's a value type not a reference type. `Form2.Location` does not point at the instance held in `camera1.LocalPosition` as value types do not have reference semantics. You are simply copying the values every time the map updates whilst dragging it (this may be 1 update or it may be 1000 updates!). I'd have a look at "value types vs reference types"

Comment: Here: http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx - this one actually talks about `Form` and the `Point` struct so it's almost exactly what you need to read. Worth reading anyway! Particularly the lines following the sentence "If we copy the objects to new variables:"

Comment: solved it, `camera1.LocalPosition + new Point(45,-270)` would still read anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try out `Form2.Location.Offset(dx, dy)`